# Elementor sticky widget in Vue 3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, elementor, sticky

I need to implement in Vue 3 a sticky widget, like the ones provided by Elementor for Wordpress.

[Here](https://tecnologia.vamtam.com/app-development/) is an example (section "Industries we’ve excelled in").

Can someone suggest me a library or some code to achieve this in Vue 3?

Thank you